# source of external function in c

Tags: c, header

I was reading a c header file and was searching for special function. I found the function with `extern` declaration, but i need to know the source of that function. considering that the containing directory is consist of many other header files how can i find the relative file for that function?

In detail i was searching for write function in `unistd.h` header file and this header has many included headers so i confused where is definition of write function.

Comment: Most functions defined in the headers have source code in the C library, and some (particularly in unistd.h) are thin wrappers where the real work is done in the operating system kernel. Why, specifically, do you need the source code for the `write` function? And what OS are you on?

Comment: Exactly i wanted to learn that what is the end function of C that invokes the system call, in case of write i followed sequence of functions and got `extern write` function in `unistd.h` header file.
so i wanted to know what is the next function and if it is last, what is system call format. i'm on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you are in Ubuntu, you should look at the glibc source code.

In general, the C library implementations of system calls are done, in assembly (not in C) with a complex series of macros, which are, for the x86 linux architecture, located in [sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/sysdep.h](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/sysdep.h) (with some in various other files elsewhere in the tree also called sysdep.h and sysdep.S) - the actual file that calls the macros to implement the write syscall is generated at compile time with several files:

- [syscalls.list](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/unix/syscalls.list)
- [make-syscalls.sh](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/unix/make-syscalls.sh)
- [syscall-template.S](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S)
- asm/unistd.h, provided by the kernel - not linked here, its main contribution is `#define __NR_write 4`

In general, the end result isn't much to look at - it takes three arguments from the stack and puts them in registers, and puts the system call number (4) in eax, then executes "ENTER_KERNEL" which was historically "int $0x80" but now is a code fragment that is in some kind of dynamic block.

Then the kernel takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

That declaration is handled by linker and there is no obvious way to locate the write function knowing just that. All you can do is to search for function's implementation in particular. This thread may help you:
http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/kernel/6871-where-do-i-find-system-call-implementation-code.html